# How to manually insert a BLOB into a SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite, blob

I want to know how to manually insert a BLOB into my SQLite database. By manually I mean, without using a driver feature that will complete the command like `setBytes`:

```java
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, aBlobColumn) VALUES (0, ?)";
stmt.setBytes(1, new byte[] {0x37, 0xe7, 0x9f});
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Is it possible to use a command like that:

```sql
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, aBlobColumn) VALUES (0, 37e79f);
```

or like that:

```sql
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, aBlobColumn) VALUES (0, BLOB(37, e7, 9f));
```

I don't mind if the command includes base64 data or raw data, I don't want to specifically use hexadecimal.

Comment: Have you tried it with base-64 encoded data?

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  I just inserted a 1 MB base-64 encoded image into a BLOB column without a problem.

Comment: There's no point in using a blob if you're storing base64 strings (Which is generally a bad idea because base 64 encoded data takes up more space than a raw binary blob.). Blob literals look like `X'hexdigits'` btw. Two digits per byte.

Comment: Yes of course, it's what I am trying to do: insert a raw binary BLOB, but using a command that can be stored as a string. The `X'hexdigits'` notation was what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following :-

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, aBlobColumn) VALUES (0, x'37e79f');
```

However, the value has to be a hex string for it to be a BLOB.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Is there a mean to use a base64 encoding or even raw data in order to shorten the command?